# What is the correct way to secure a user directory with EFS not in a domain network?

Tags: windows, encryption, windows-10, cipher

Logged in as an administrator on a Windows 10 machine.

```
cipher /E /A /S:C:\Users\MYUSER
```

or

```
cipher /E C:\Users\MYUSER
```

I've read and been told that the bottom one is the correct way.

End result: Encrypt all the files and ensure new and copied files are encrypted. I think I did something wrong because eventually files stopped being encrypted.